# Post for from jQuery UI dialog

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to integrate new functionality using jQuery UI's dialog.

I have a page with a link. When a link is clicked a modal dialog with a form in it opens. That part works OK.

```
$("#myForm").hide();
$("#myLink").click(function(){
    $("#myForm").dialog({
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 450,
        buttons: {
            "Submit": function() {
                // ???
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});

<a href="#" id="myLink">Open Dialog</a>

<div id="myForm">
    <form>
      <textarea id="myValues" rows="10"></textarea>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now, I need to submit the form from within my dialog and POST results to the same page. I am getting all confused with how to implement the rest. I did look at the jQuery .post() example which made me even more confused. The page is in PHP, so when the results are submitted I need to get the post value and do some server-site action.

```
if (isset($_POST["myValues"])) {
   // do something
}
```

Stuck, need help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery function for "Submit" button:

```
$('form#myFormId').submit();
```

And in HTML:

```
<form id="myFormId" method="POST" action="processingscript.php">
```

Then the php script will get all the values that have been POSTed and can process them.

Comment: Oh, I think this is what I was looking for. For some reason I kept looking at AJAX stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Look into using the jQuery submit function

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 1):

Use this method that updates dialog content:

```
              $("#myformid").dialog({
              modal: true,
               draggable: false,
               resizable: false,
               width: 450,
                buttons: {
                    "Submit": function (event) {

                        event.preventDefault();
                        var formvalues = $("#myformid").serialize();
                        $.post('/Home/Edit', formvalues, function (data) {
                           //use data
                            $('#myformid').html(data);

                        }, "html");

                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }

            });
```

In the Control,

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Edit(ViewModel model) {

       //use data

        return PartialView("MyDialogView", model);
    }
```